# Selenium2 Webdriver taking screen shot works for Firefox but nothing else

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot

I am using Selenium 2 with Testng.
selenium-java-2.33.0

Trying to take a screen shot of the browser only on failed test cases.  I am storing the webdriver in Hashtable with an id associated with each browser type (IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari).  In the Cleanup routine "@afterMethod", I fetch that webdriver.  Here is the code:

//Code 1:

```
if (webDriver instanceof TakesScreenshot) {
    File tempFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(tempFile, new File("screenshots.png"));
}
```

//Code 2:

```
EventFiringWebDriver efiringDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(webDriver);
File scrFile = efiringDriver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("screenshot.png"));
```

Both of the code paths works for Firefox, but for other browsers, an cast exception is thrown.

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: How do you instantiate the `driver`?

Comment: It seems that somewhere you have used firefox instance and casted it to Chrome driver instance. Give more code where you have instantiated the driver and called the above method.

Comment: // gets populated during runtime  
Hashtable<Long, WebDriver> listOfDrivers;    

// Procedure below gets executed at @AfterMethod
WebDriver wd = (WebDriver)listOfDrivers.get(identifier);
EventFiringWebDriver efiringDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(wd);
return (efiringDriver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE));

Comment: I have tried running the test using ONLY Chrome, and still encountered the same exception.  Is the TakesScreenShot and EventFiringWebDriver, compatible with other Non-Firefox webdrivers?

Comment: Here is the bare code, there is not browser casting involved.


WebDriver driver = new WebDriver(new ChromeDriver());


driver.get("http://www.google.com");



File file = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);